# Using raw sql in django

Tags: mysql, sql, django

What would be the equivalent raw sql for the following:

```
def index:
    Emails.objects.create(email=request.POST['invite_email'])
```

I have this so far, but I can't quite get the quotations working --

```
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("insert into splash_emails (id, email) values ('0','request.POST[invite_email]')")
    transaction.commit_unless_managed()
```

What would be correct way to write this, and is this the simplest way to perform raw sql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you ever want to see the queries django is using you can do:

```
emails = Emails.objects.create(email=request.POST['invite_email'])
print emails.query
```

It's a bit verbose, but you'll get the gist.

Answer (score 2):

I think after reading the Django cookbook chapter on [Security](http://www.djangobook.com/en/1.0/chapter19/), you'll have a good idea on how to execute raw sql AND execute it safely.